# Is there a PHP library/class for manipulating units & quantities?

Tags: php, class, units-of-measurement

I am looking for a PHP library/class to manipulate units and quantities in a similar way to what the [`ruby-units`](https://github.com/olbrich/ruby-units) gems does. I have found a port of that Ruby library to JavaScript called [`js-quantities`](https://github.com/gentooboontoo/js-quantities), but not to PHP.

**Are there any PHP libraries/classses for manipulating units & quantities out there?**

Answer (score 3):

[**Zend Framework 1**](http://framework.zend.com/) did inlcude a component called [`Zend_Measure`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.measure.html) which is quite sophisticated but was dropped from **Zend Framework 2**.

Comment: Here is a discussion on the potential re-inclusion of `Zend_Measure` into `ZF2`: https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/3103#issuecomment-11261644

Answer (score 2):

I've been searching for the same thing and came across https://github.com/triplepoint/php-units-of-measure

I haven't tried it myself yet, but it looks to be very complete.

Edit:  I looked a bit at the class referenced above for what I was wanting and it didn't go into the US equivalent measures like teaspoons and tablespoons.  The class can be enhanced, but I think I'll continue along my own path as I have been.